# I am getting Type mismatch error while applying autofilter to filter the records absed on criteria on two columns in from second sheet

Tags: excel, vba, types, mismatch

I have data on sheets "Combined" and PercentageSetter"

1. columns in Combined sheets are Scrip, Allocation %
2. columns in PercentageSetter Sheet are Scrip, Min % and Max%
   I am trying to create a VBA macro to autofilter Combined sheet base on values in PercentageSetter sheet as bellow
   criteria:
   The combined sheet should only display records for which Scrip matches Scrip in PercentageSetter and its Allocation% should be between Min% and Max% (both inclusive).

below is my code, but it gives error Type Mismatch on line .AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:=">=" & Application.Transpose(MinPercentArray), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Application.Transpose(MaxPercentArray)

```
Private Sub ApplyFilter()
 
    Dim IncludeArray() As String
    Dim MinPercentArray() As Variant
    Dim MaxPercentArray() As Variant
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wsCombined As Worksheet
    Dim wsPercentageSetter As Worksheet

    Set wsCombined = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combined")
    Set wsPercentageSetter = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PercentageSetter")
    
    With wsPercentageSetter
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim IncludeArray(lastrow - 1)
        ReDim MinPercentArray(lastrow - 1)
        ReDim MaxPercentArray(lastrow - 1)
        ' assumes a header row so start in row 2
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            IncludeArray(i - 2) = .Range("A" & i).Text
            MinPercentArray(i - 2) = .Range("B" & i).value
            MaxPercentArray(i - 2) = .Range("C" & i).value
            
        Next i
    End With

            'Debug.Print wsCombined.Range("H2")
            'Debug.Print VarType(wsCombined.Range("H2").value)
    


   With wsCombined.Rows("2:" & wsCombined.Rows.count)
    .AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:=MinPercentArray, Operator:=xlFilterValues
    .AutoFilter field:=8, Criteria1:=">=" & Application.Transpose(MinPercentArray), Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & Application.Transpose(MaxPercentArray)
End With
End Sub
```

Thanks for all helping me out in advance.

I have already tried searching google , tried changing array to double but not working

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your VBA macro is likely due to how you're using Application.Transpose and applying AutoFilter with arrays.

Probably You'll need to loop through each row in the "Combined" sheet, check if its Scrip matches with any Scrip in the "PercentageSetter" sheet, and then verify if the Allocation % falls within the Min % and Max % range. If it does, the row is shown; otherwise, it's hidden.

```
Private Sub ApplyFilter()
    Dim wsCombined As Worksheet, wsPercentageSetter As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowCombined As Long, lastRowPercentageSetter As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim scrip As String, allocation As Double, minPerc As Double, maxPerc As Double

    Set wsCombined = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Combined")
    Set wsPercentageSetter = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PercentageSetter")

    lastRowCombined = wsCombined.Cells(wsCombined.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    lastRowPercentageSetter = wsPercentageSetter.Cells(wsPercentageSetter.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    wsCombined.AutoFilterMode = False

    For i = 2 To lastRowCombined
        scrip = wsCombined.Cells(i, 1).Value
        allocation = wsCombined.Cells(i, 2).Value
        wsCombined.Rows(i).Hidden = True

        For j = 2 To lastRowPercentageSetter
            If wsPercentageSetter.Cells(j, 1).Value = scrip Then
                minPerc = wsPercentageSetter.Cells(j, 2).Value
                maxPerc = wsPercentageSetter.Cells(j, 3).Value

                If allocation >= minPerc And allocation <= maxPerc Then
                    wsCombined.Rows(i).Hidden = False
                    Exit For
                End If
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```